# Enable signalr to accept WS connections

Tags: websocket, .net-core, signalr

I have created a dotnet core signalr project, and I want to allow other users to connect on the signalr web socket like I can do it when I connect on:

`wss://echo.websocket.org`

Currently, `signalr` generates `ID` when creating the negotiation, and when switching on `wss` it uses that id, but it is causing a problem when using external connections.

So, is it possible to tell SignalR not to generate the id when creating the websocket server, and also to accept external ws connections ?

Answer (score 1):

try to use dotnet core websockets

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.2